# fastreport Hide Elements in DataBand depending on Data

Tags: c#, .net, fastreport

In a Report designed with fastreport we want to hide or Show an Image Object in the Data Band Depending on the given Data (e.g. a Boolean Property).

I know that I can set the Visibilty of Objects with C# by Adressing the Object by its Name, but inside a DataBand the Object with the Name is there multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, next approach may help. I often use this approach, when I want to manipulate objects in databand depending on data.
Just put your logic in `OnBeforePrint` event for given band in FastReport editor. Every object (including TfrxPictureView) has a name in FastReport editor and you can access it by this name.

Next example is working:

*Pascal Script*

```
procedure MasterData1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
   Picture1.Visible := (<reportdataset."YourField"> = 'YourValue');                                                 
end;
```

*C++ Script*

```
void MasterData1OnBeforePrint(TfrxComponent Sender)
{
   Picture1.Visible = (<reportdataset."YourField"> == "YourValue");                                                 
}
```

*C# Script*

```
void MasterData1OnBeforePrint(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Picture1.Visible = ((string)Report.GetColumnValue("reportdataset.YourField") == "YourValue");                                                 
}
```